# fix two decision variables in bilevel optimization model

Tags: python, pyomo

There is a bilevel optimization model and I try to deal with it in Pyomo. Two decision variables are in the upper level objective function. When I introduce the lower level objective function, how to fix the two decision variables simultaneously?
I tried to fix the two decision variables (model.o_recommonded and model.cost)in my code.

```
# intruduce lower level
fixed_variables = [model.o_recommonded[h, i] for h in range(experts) for i in range(alternatives)]
fixed_variables.extend([model.cost[h] for h in range(experts)])
model.Lower = SubModel(fixed=fixed_variables)
```

But I am not sure the code is right. If there are some errors in my code, please tell me.